# Fill a javascript circle in slices

Tags: javascript, canvas, automatic-ref-counting

I want the circle to resemble a pie chart with equal slices of different colors. For some reason the I'm drawing a circle, with arcs on the side with the colors, with a white octagon in the center.

```
for(var i=0;i<8;i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle= 'rgb(' + Math.floor(255-42.5*i) + ', 95, 180)';
    ctx.arc(300,300,radius,i*((Math.PI*2)/8),(i+1)*((Math.PI*2)/8)); 
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: Some more details would be nice. I don't really see a problem statement there

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you draw an arc that is less than a full circle, all that it is doing is creating just the arc, and bounding it with itself, not with the center. However, if we force it to move to the center, then it would draw the slice as opposed to the arc. I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q46vf/2/) to demonstrate it.

The updated code is this

```
var ctx=document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var radius=100;
for(var i=0;i<8;i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle='rgb(' + Math.floor(255-42.5*i) + ', 95, 180)';
    ctx.moveTo(300,300); //We have to add this, otherwise, it will fill the minimum area needed to fill the arc

    ctx.arc(300,300,radius,i*Math.PI/4,(i+1)*((Math.PI/4)),false); 
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: Incredible and magnificent. That's exactly what my problem was. Thank you!